# Table Disobeys W3C Box Model, Ie8 Ignores Fixed Table Width !

Tags: internet-explorer-8, model, w3c

I'm having hard time with tables and column widths.

Update: I'm using XHTML Strict 1.0.

The page is: http://www.pro-turk.net/try

The first problem I have is, I have a column with a fixed width of 100px and 4px padding, but it disobeys my padding depending on the value. The column width (as the distance between two borders according to W3C Box Model) is 156 px even if padding is 0 or 4. Only the position of the text changes.

According to W3C Box Model ( available at www.pro-turk.net/box_model.png ), borders and paddings aren't included in WIDTH attribute, so why does it render wrongly ?

The second problem is, when you look the page I gave with IE8, the first cell in the second row has 150px fixed width, but ie shows it about 50% of the total table width regardless of what i say.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the default [`auto` table-layout mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#auto-table-layout). That lets the browser decide fairly arbitrarily how much space to assign to each column, usually depending on the amount of actual content in the cells. In this mode, `width` is little more than advisory.

If you want the browser to take your column widths seriously you should set `table-layout: fixed` on the `<table>` element, and either include `<col/>` elements with explicit widths, or set widths on the cells in the first row, for the columns you want to be fixed-width. (The other columns will share the remain width equally.) `fixed` table layout also allows the browser to render faster.

For your page you might be better off with CSS positioning. Certainly for the internal table that seems to exist only to float-left the image. Nested tables are to be avoided.